# PHP http_build_query generating a ® sign when I write reg, how to escape?

Tags: php

I have the following code:

```
$data1 = [
            "user_number" => "423423",  // unique_id
            "reg_date" => "2013-01-20", // date of registration yyyy-mm-dd

];

echo http_build_query($data1);
```

This is generating the following string:

```
user_number=423423®_date=2013-01-20
```

As you can see, it converts "reg" to ®, breaking the API query. How to prevent it from doing that?

Comment: are you outputting in utf8?

Comment: http_build_query is a php function

Comment: [Can't reproduce](https://3v4l.org/prsZ3)

Comment: yes, I have to output it in utf8

Comment: `echo http_build_query($data1,'','&amp;');`

Comment: worked! why? @Alex

Comment: check @Quentin answer, he has a very good explanation :-)

Answer (score 2):

`&reg` is how you write a registered trademark symbol in HTML.

Your URL is fine, the problem is that you are interpreting it as a URL in HTML and not a URL in plain text.

Use `htmlspecialchars` to convert the string to HTML source code.

Answer (score 0):

The file (physical file .php) you are coding may be in ISO-8859-1 or similar.

You need to convert your file to UTF-8 to avoid this problem.

You may also want to apply a function to solve convert special chars:

```
echo htmlspecialchars(http_build_query($data1));
echo htmlentities(http_build_query($data1));
```

Both will work.

The issue here is that `&reg` is encoded as ®.
By using functions to replace these special chars, it will render the way you want.
The online php interpreters probably use those, that's why we can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo http_build_query($data1,'','&amp;');
```

&reg is how you write a registered trademark symbol in HTML.

that means your original code returns

```
user_number=423423&reg_date=2013-01-20
```

and when you output to browser browser converts `&reg` part to (r)